# Python selenium won't click a button by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to build a bot to automatically vote on google forms. Problem is, My bot can't click the submit button. It clicks on the button to select the vote, but not the submit button. No error occurs, the button simply doesn't get clicked.

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("{not posting link for privacy}")

time.sleep(5)

vote = driver.find_element_by_id("i92")
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/span/span')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(vote)
actions.click(submit)
actions.perform()

print('submit' + str(submit))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using an action chain?

Comment: Am I not supposed to? How do I not use one?

Comment: Just use vote.click() and submit.click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure why you dont just use submit.click()

something like this :

```
    app2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("blah blah blah")
    app2.click()
```

you can also send keys by

```
app2.send_keys("hello there") or app2.send_keys(Keys=RETURN) #"enter"
```